# Aws XRay "Entity doesn't exist in CallContext" in .net console application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have a setup for SQSClient like this:

```
var client = new AmazonSQSClient();
new AWSSdkTracingHandler(AWSXRayRecorder.Instance).AddEventHandler(client);
return client;
```

now when i call the client

```
var receiveResult = _amazonSqs.ReceiveMessage(_longPollRequest);
```

I get the following exception

```
Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Exceptions.EntityNotAvailableException was 
unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Entity doesn't exist in CallContext
Source=AWSXRayRecorder.Core
StackTrace:
   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Internal.Utils.TraceContext.GetEntity() in c:\Jenkins\jobs\net-release\workspace\sdk\src\Core\Internal\Utils\TraceContext.cs:line 47
   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Handlers.AwsSdk.AWSSdkTracingHandler.ExceptionEventHandler(Object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\jobs\net-release\workspace\sdk\src\Handlers\AwsSdk\AWSSdkTracingHandler.cs:line 324
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.ProcessExceptionHandlers(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller)
   at Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSClient.ReceiveMessage(ReceiveMessageRequest request)
   at BasePriceCalculator.Library.Services.AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.Listen() in C:\working\base-price-calculator\BasePriceCalculator.Library\Services\AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.cs:line 74
   at BasePriceCalculator.BasePriceCalculatorService.<Start>b__3_0() in C:\working\base-price-calculator\BasePriceCalculator\BasePriceCalculatorService.cs:line 26
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

i have tried adding something like `AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.BeginSegment();` but somehow that requires a `traceId` that i can't seem to satisfy

```
AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.BeginSegment("ReceiveMessage", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
var receiveResult = _amazonSqs.ReceiveMessage(_longPollRequest);
AWSXRayRecorder.Instance.EndSegment();
```

exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Trace id is invalid.
Parameter name: value
ParamName=value
Source=AWSXRayRecorder.Core
StackTrace:
   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Internal.Entities.Entity.set_TraceId(String value) in c:\Jenkins\jobs\net-release\workspace\sdk\src\Core\Internal\Entities\Entity.cs:line 78
   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Internal.Entities.Segment..ctor(String name, String traceId, String parentId) in c:\Jenkins\jobs\net-release\workspace\sdk\src\Core\Internal\Entities\Segment.cs:line 46
   at Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.AWSXRayRecorder.BeginSegment(String name, String traceId, String parentId, SampleDecision sampleDecision) in c:\Jenkins\jobs\net-release\workspace\sdk\src\Core\AWSXRayRecorder.cs:line 164
   at BasePriceCalculator.Library.Services.AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.<Listen>b__10_1() in C:\working\base-price-calculator\BasePriceCalculator.Library\Services\AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.cs:line 65
   at StatsdClient.DogStatsdService.Time[T](Func`1 func, String statName, Double sampleRate, String[] tags)
   at StatsdClient.DogStatsd.Time[T](Func`1 func, String statName, Double sampleRate, String[] tags)
   at DataDogUtils.DataDogMetricPublisher.Time[T](Func`1 func, String statName, Double sampleRate, String[] tags)
   at BasePriceCalculator.Library.Services.AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.<Listen>b__10_0() in C:\working\base-price-calculator\BasePriceCalculator.Library\Services\AwsSqsCalculationMessageListener.cs:line 63
   at Polly.Policy`1.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.<ExecuteAndCapture>b__0(Context ctx, CancellationToken ct) in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Policy.TResult.cs:line 194
   at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.Implementation[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IEnumerable`1 shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, IEnumerable`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`1 policyStateFactory) in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetryEngine.cs:line 26
```

I must be doing something wrong, but i am not seeing it.

Comment: Try to ask the question on their official forum. The amazon guys are really responsive there. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=241&start=0

Comment: i tried: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261162 but i am not getting the same reaction you got i guess :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new Trace ID using `TraceId.NewId();`. This class is available in the `Amazon.XRay.Recorder.Core.Internal.Entities` namespace.

As Ruslan mentioned, we (the AWS X-Ray team) are very active on the AWS X-Ray official forum. Unfortunately, your linked post appears to have been posted in the AWS .NET language specific forum. We're much more likely to quickly respond to future posts if they're made to the [X-Ray specific forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=241&start=0).

Thanks,

James B.

Comment: Thank you so much, how the hell was i supposed to find that out :)

Comment: No problem. I've submitted a request to expose the `Internal` namespaces in our .NET SDK [API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-dotnet/latest/reference/html/N_Amazon_XRay_Recorder_Core.htm).

Comment: How about an overload where you just automatically do the ```TraceId.NewId();``` for us, as it appears to work in node.js version?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. We'll look into adding that, thanks.